# how to get INFOPLIST_FILE name iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, plist

Each target in my project has to has different info.plist. I want to get the name programmatically from BuildSettings> Packaging> Info.plist file but somehow I cant really retrieve the plist list filename. Is there a way i can retrieve the plist programmatically?

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleInfoPlistURL")
```

only gives me

```
Info.plist -- file:///Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXXX-9B37-4C3D-88E9-XXXXX62B470/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7XXXXXXXB-BE36-4D3E-9C90-XXXXX/PROJECT%20KOL.app/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually `NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleInfoPlistURL")` returns an NSURL object. Extract the absoluteString from it which will give you the name of your plist file. Check the code below. Sorry for giving answer in `Objective-C` as I don't know `Swift`

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary;
NSString *plistFilePath = [[infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleInfoPlistURL"] absoluteString];
NSString *plistFileName = [[plistFilePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
```

plistFileName is the required file name (with extension .plist)